# When does Kirby increase in size?

Tags: kirbys-dream-buffet

Eating strawberries in Kirby's Dream Buffet causes Kirby to increase in size. Are these growth points preset? If so, how many strawberries does Kirby need to eat for each increase in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirby has 7 possible sizes depending on how many strawberries he's eaten.

- 0 - 9 strawberries
- 10 - 59 strawberries
- 60 - 119 strawberries
- 120 - 199 strawberries
- 200 - 299 strawberries
- 300 - 499 strawberries
- 500 - 999 strawberries

If you do a Single Battle Royal match instead of a full Gourmet Grand Prix, you seem to start at a larger size. The change intervals seem to be the same based on a test round where I got 130 strawberries.